# How is SOAPInterceptor.getUnderstoodHeaders() used?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

When is [`SoapInterceptor.getUnderstoodHeaders()`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/interceptor/SoapInterceptor.html#getUnderstoodHeaders%28%29) actually called by Apache CXF and what impact does it have on the use of interceptor?

What is the impact of having this function return `null` or an empty `HashSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to declare the undestood header by the interceptor.

If you declare an header as must understand you have to create an interceptor that manages it